# Why floating point numbers are accurate while arithmetic operations are not?

Tags: java

Why floating point numbers are accurate while arithmetic operations are not? I mean doesn't compiler rounds to the nearest number to represent double numbers not only arithmetic operation results?

```
double a = 0.1;
double b = 0.2;
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(a + b);
```

outputs;

```
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
```

What I expected;

```
0.10000000000000001
0.20000000000000003
0.30000000000000004
```

**EDIT:**
What is the difference between these operations;

```
double a = 0.3;
double b = 0.1 + 0.2;
System.out.println(a);   //0.3
System.out.println(b);   //0.300000000000004
```

Comment: 1. please read *[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)*. 2. floating point may be *precise* but it is not *accurate*.

Comment: @Richard I know 0.3 cant be represent correctly with binary numbers but I don't get how it prints 0.3 when I define a double number with 0.3 as value. How it stores this number?

Comment: What is the reasoning behind your expected output?

Comment: Are you really asking: why does Java sometimes round floating point values and at other times does not?

Comment: @Richard yes. When I print 0.1 I expected to see a number like 0.10000002 as output. I mean it can't represent 0.1 as binary number but it prints 0.1 correctly.

Comment: Contrary to what is stated in the accepted answer, it's not because the bit pattern is *different*. `println` finds the *shortest possible* decimal that, when converted back into binary, would give *the same binary representation*. That is how they can round `1.00000000000000005551115123126E-1` to `0.1` on output. Due to the inaccuracies involved in converting 0.1 and 0.2 to binary, and then adding them up, the resulting bit pattern is **closer** to decimal `0.30000000000000004` than it is to `0.3`, and thus the output routines cannot round it to `0.3`, because that would be a rounding error.

Comment: (ctd.) So yes, when `println` shows you `0.1`, it is telling you a "white lie": That is not the *closest* decimal approximation to the binary value, but the *shortest* (which is usually what you expect to see). After a couple of operations, inaccuracies can add up to the point where this "rounding trick" stops working as expected. In any case a good implementation will ensure that the decimal-binary-decimal round-trip of values does not introduce errors. (That was not always the case, this is a surprisingly young art, the seminal paper being published as recently as 1990.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When converting the literals (for example with [this](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=048046051) converter) you will see that the bit representation is the **most precise** one. However the **actual** stored value slightly differs which leads to:

`0.1` = `1.00000000000000005551115123126E-1`
`0.2` = `2.00000000000000011102230246252E-1` and
`0.3` = `2.99999999999999988897769753748E-1`

And as you can see the sum of the literal's representation does add up to `0.30000000000000004` but will not produce the same bit pattern as the literal for `0.3` and therefore the outputted value is not treated equally to the literal of `0.3`.